# jquery checkbox click function created with JSON not working

Tags: jquery, json, checkbox, cakephp-1.3

I have a `jquery-ajax` function which created a list of checkboxes.

```
success: function(msg){

    jQuery.each(msg.gal_sublocations, function(index, gal_sublocation) {
        html += '<input type="checkbox" name="data[GalStore][gal_sublocation_id][]" value = "'+gal_sublocation.GalSublocation.id+'" class="chkbx" id="sublocation_'+gal_sublocation.GalSublocation.id+'" />'+gal_sublocation.GalSublocation.name;

        $('#load_sublocations').html(html);
       alert(html);
       $('#sublocation_'+gal_sublocation.GalSublocation.id).click(function(){
            alert('Checked !');
        });

    });  

}
```

The `alert(html)` produces final alert as

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[GalStore][gal_sublocation_id][]" value = "99" class="chkbx" id="sublocation_99" />Beltola
<input type="checkbox" name="data[GalStore][gal_sublocation_id][]" value = "101" class="chkbx" id="sublocation_101" />Dispur
<input type="checkbox" name="data[GalStore][gal_sublocation_id][]" value = "102" class="chkbx" id="sublocation_102" />Paltan Bazar
<input type="checkbox" name="data[GalStore][gal_sublocation_id][]" value = "100" class="chkbx" id="sublocation_100" />Patarkuchi
```

But when I click on the checkboxes, it is not alerting anything ! Whats the matter ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jquery On() because your code append after loading.

use like this;

```
$(".class").on('click', function(){
 // ajax operation
}}
```

Comment: Hi Mehmet..it also not working ! same . only the last checkbox working !

Answer (score 0):

While creating your input string, better to create a node right there:

```
var html = $("<input />").attr({
    "type" : "checkbox",
    "name" : data[GalStore][gal_sublocation_id][],
    "id" : 'sublocation_' + gal_sublocation.GalSublocation.id,
    "class" : "chkbx"
})
.val(gal_sublocation.GalSublocation.id)
.click(function(){
      alert('Checked !');
}); 

$('#load_sublocations').append(html);
```

Comment: Hi Ashish, its not working ! Its not even populating the checkboxes :(

Comment: Really, do a check here: http://jsfiddle.net/8wtJG/1/
things commented because those data are coming from your ajax and in my example, not available.